# Open-liberty how to setup a log4j configuration?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, open-liberty

title says it all. How do I setup a log4j configuration in my Open-liberty project? I've added my log4j.xml file in the resources folder and I use the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my server.xml:

```
<server description="Intake Server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <feature>mpConfig-1.4</feature>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <variable name="default.http.port" defaultValue="9080"/>
    <variable name="default.https.port" defaultValue="9443"/>
    <variable name="app.context.root" defaultValue="message"/>


    <httpEndpoint httpPort="${default.http.port}" 
    httpsPort="${default.https.port}" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"  host="*" />

    <library id="log4jConfig">
          <folder dir="/var/log/intake" scanInterval="5s" />
    </library>


    <webApplication id="intake" location="intake.war" contextRoot="${app.context.root}">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="log4jConfig"/>
    </webApplication>
</server>
```

Comment: Your library is not log4j2 but log4j 1.2.17. Try last log4j2 version: 2.17.0

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to add log4j to the classpath, and there's several ways you can do that (with pros/cons to each, but I would suggest #2, unless you have more then one app that's going to be making use of log4j, in which case 3 may be the better approach):

1. Package it with your app (inside the war)
2. Add it in the server.xml via the [classloader](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/classloader.html) attribute under your [webApplication](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/webApplication.html)
3. Drop it in the [global shared library folder](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/directory-locations-properties.html): `${shared.config.dir}/lib/global` or `${server.config.dir}/lib/global`
4. Set it via JVM argument: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/path/to/log4j2.xml`

I'll mention that there is also an [archived repo regarding using log4j with Open Liberty](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/archived-guide-log4j) that you may find helpful, but keep in mind that it is archived so it's likely incomplete and with no dev support.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I followed the tutorial provided in the repository but it unfortunately doesn't work. I tried the second option as you suggested. It finds my log4j2.xml file but doesn't implement it and LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(CLASS); returns null.

Comment: can you update the question to show your server.xml snippet with what you added for #2?

Comment: I updated my answer and added the server.xml file.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. I updated my question with the server.xml file, if you could give a quick look I would really appreciate it!